# how to load a txt file into JTextArea line by line

Tags: java

i want to load txt file into JtextArea ,There were always show error messages,although i have been tried to use apends() or Settext()
below is code

```
`  JmenuItem.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {  
                try
                {
                JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();
                int option = open.showOpenDialog(open);
                File f1 = new File(open.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String s=null;
                while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
                {   textArea.setText(s);
                    textArea.setText("\n");

                }
                fr.close();
                } catch(FileNotFoundException z){       
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "file not found");
                  }catch (IOException z) { z.printStackTrace();  }
                 }
                }           

            );
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(40,40);
    }
    }
```

`

Comment: what are the error messages?

Comment: If you want have a look at Java Scanner and try-catch with resources from java 7. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html

Comment: thanks for sharing.